# How do I breed a Peridot dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

With the coming of August comes the inclusion of a new Gemstone dragon to the world of *DragonVale*.

This dragon is known as the Peridot dragon.

**What dragons do I need to breed to get a Peridot dragon?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cactus and Crystal is a good combo.  Another good combination is Fog and Iron.

Answer (score 1):

after 5 tries Cactus & Crystal provided a peridot :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure of Cactus+Crystal. All other sites say so.

Answer (score -1):

Cactus and crystal works the best for me.

Comment: Hi Hazza, welcome to the site. This site is not for offering to do trades with members, but instead for answering questions that people have. Please [read the FAQ](http://arqade.com/faq) for more details on what makes a good answer.